# k-d tree for nearest neighbors alternative to pdist2

Tags: matlab, image-processing, computer-vision, image-recognition, kdtree

I am currently computing the nearest neighbors ratio using pdist2 for two feature vectors, x and y. I am using pdist2 to get the distances and am then sorting the distances by column and computing column 1 / column2 for the nearest neighbors ratio. I thought it would be faster to use a k-d tree to do this. Is this possible using built in matlab function?

Comment: [KDTreeSearcher](http://mathworks.com/help/stats/kdtreesearcher-object.html)?

Comment: I tried it but it lowers my accuracy. Should I expect this?

Comment: So please edit your question to include a minimal example showing what you tried, and why that doesn't work for you.